# Interaction with MailboxProcessor and Task hangs forever

Tags: f#, task-parallel-library, mailboxprocessor

I want to process a series of jobs in sequence, but I want to queue up those jobs in parallel.

Here is my code:

```ml
open System.Threading.Tasks

let performWork (work : int) =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay 1000

    if work = 7 then
      failwith "Oh no"
    else
      printfn $"Work {work}"
  }

async {
  let w = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
    while true do
      let! message = inbox.Receive()

      let (ch : AsyncReplyChannel<_>), work = message

      do!
        performWork work
        |> Async.AwaitTask

      ch.Reply()
  })

  w.Error.Add(fun exn -> raise exn)

  let! completed =
    seq {
      for i = 1 to 10 do
        async {
          do! Async.Sleep 100
          do! w.PostAndAsyncReply(fun ch -> ch, i)

          return i
        }
    }
    |> fun jobs -> Async.Parallel(jobs, maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4)

  printfn $"Completed {Seq.length completed} job(s)."
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

I expect this code to crash once it reaches work item `7`.

However, it hangs forever:

```sh
$ dotnet fsi ./Test.fsx
Work 3
Work 1
Work 2
Work 4
Work 5
Work 6
```

I think that the `w.Error` event is not firing correctly.

How should I be capturing and re-throwing this error?

If my work is `async`, then it crashes as expected:

```ml
let performWork (work : int) =
  async {
    do! Async.Sleep 1000

    if work = 7 then
      failwith "Oh no"
    else
      printfn $"Work {work}"
  }
```

But I don't see why this should matter.

---

Leveraging a `Result` also works, but again, I don't know why this should be required.

```ml
async {
  let w = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
    while true do
      let! message = inbox.Receive()

      let (ch : AsyncReplyChannel<_>), work = message

      try
        do!
          performWork work
          |> Async.AwaitTask

        ch.Reply(Ok ())
      with exn ->
        ch.Reply(Error exn)
  })

  let performWorkOnWorker (work : int) =
    async {
      let! outcome = w.PostAndAsyncReply(fun ch -> ch, work)

      match outcome with
      | Ok () ->
        return ()
      | Error exn ->
        return raise exn
    }

  let! completed =
    seq {
      for i = 1 to 10 do
        async {
          do! Async.Sleep 100
          do! performWorkOnWorker i

          return i
        }
    }
    |> fun jobs -> Async.Parallel(jobs, maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4)

  printfn $"Completed {Seq.length completed} job(s)."
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: This is curious. I tried `async` as you suggest and it does crash as you state. Simply changing `do! Async.Sleep 1000` to `do! Task.Delay 1000 |> Async.AwaitTask` within also changes the behaviour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the gist of the 'why' here is that Microsoft changed the behaviour for 'unobserved' task exceptions back in .NET 4.5, and this was brought through into .NET Core: these exceptions no longer cause the process to terminate, they're effectively ignored. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-6.0).

I don't know the ins and outs of how `Task` and `async` are interoperating, but it would seem that the use of `Task` results in the continuations being attached to that and run on the `TaskScheduler` as a consequence. The exception is thrown as part of the `async` computation within the `MailboxProcessor`, and nothing is 'observing' it. This means the exception ends up in the mechanism referred to above, and that's why your process no longer crashes.

You can change this behaviour via a flag on .NET Framework via `app.config`, as explained in the link above. For .NET Core, you can't do this. You'd ordinarily try and replicate this by subscribing to the `UnobservedTaskException` event and re-throwing there, but that won't work in this case as the `Task` is hung and won't ever be garbage collected.

To try and prove the point, I've amended your example to include a timeout for `PostAndReplyAsync`. This means that the `Task` *will* eventually complete, can be garbage collected and, when the finaliser runs, the event fired.

```ml
open System
open System.Threading.Tasks

let performWork (work : int) =
  task {
    do! Task.Delay 1000

    if work = 7 then
      failwith "Oh no"
    else
      printfn $"Work {work}"
  }

let worker = async {
  let w = MailboxProcessor.Start (fun inbox -> async {
    while true do
      let! message = inbox.Receive()

      let (ch : AsyncReplyChannel<_>), work = message

      do!
        performWork work
        |> Async.AwaitTask

      ch.Reply()
  })

  w.Error.Add(fun exn -> raise exn)

  let! completed =
    seq {
      for i = 1 to 10 do
        async {
          do! Async.Sleep 100
          do! w.PostAndAsyncReply((fun ch -> ch, i), 10000)

          return i
        }
    }
    |> fun jobs -> Async.Parallel(jobs, maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4)

  printfn $"Completed {Seq.length completed} job(s)."

}

TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException.Add(fun ex ->
    printfn "UnobservedTaskException was fired, re-raising"
    raise ex.Exception)

try
  Async.RunSynchronously worker
with
  | :? TimeoutException -> ()

GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

The output I get here is:

```
Work 1
Work 3
Work 4
Work 2
Work 5
Work 6
UnobservedTaskException was fired, re-raising
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. (One or more errors occurred. (Oh no))
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Oh no)
 ---> System.Exception: Oh no
   at Program.performWork@5.MoveNext() in /Users/cmager/dev/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp2/Program.fs:line 9
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.Start@1078-1.Invoke(ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.Trampoline.Execute(FSharpFunc`2 firstAction) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 104
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.AsyncPrimitives.AttachContinuationToTask@1144.Invoke(Task`1 completedTask) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 1145
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Program.clo@46-4.Invoke(UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs ex) in /Users/cmager/dev/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp2/Program.fs:line 48
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CommonExtensions.SubscribeToObservable@1989.System.IObserver<'T>.OnNext(T args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\async.fs:line 1990
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.h@379.Invoke(Object _arg1, TArgs args) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\fsharp\FSharp.Core\seqcore.fs:line 379
   at Program.clo@46-3.Invoke(Object delegateArg0, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs delegateArg1) in /Users/cmager/dev/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp2/Program.fs:line 46
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.PublishUnobservedTaskException(Object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs ueea)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
```

As you can see, the exception is eventually published by the `Task` finaliser, and re-throwing it in that handler brings down the app.

While interesting, I'm not sure any of this is practically useful information. The suggestion to terminate the app within `MailboxProcessor.Error` handler is probably the right one.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is in your error handling:

```ml
w.Error.Add(fun exn -> raise exn)
```

Instead of handling the exception, you're attempting to raise it again, which I think is causing an infinite loop.

You can change this to print the exception instead:

```ml
w.Error.Add(printfn "%A")
```

Result is:

```sh
Work 4
Work 2
Work 1
Work 3
Work 5
Work 6
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Oh no)
 ---> System.Exception: Oh no
   at Program.performWork@4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Brian Berns\Source\Repos\FsharpConsole\FsharpConsole\Program.fs:line 8
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, when you throw an exception in the MailboxProcessor Body. Then the MailboxProcessor doesn't hang forever, it just stops the whole MailboxProcessor.

Your program also hangs, well because you do a `Async.Parallel` and wait until every async finished. But those with an exception, never finish, or returns a result. So your program overall, hangs forever.

If you want to explicitly abort, then you need to call `System.Environment.Exit`, not just throw an exception.

One way to re-write your program is like this.

```ml
open System.Threading.Tasks

let performWork (work : int) = task {
    do! Task.Delay 1000

    if   work = 7
    then failwith "Oh no"
    else printfn $"Work {work}"
}

let mb =
    let mbBody (inbox : MailboxProcessor<AsyncReplyChannel<_> * int>) = async {
        while true do
            let! (ch,work) = inbox.Receive()
            try
                do! performWork work |> Async.AwaitTask
                ch.Reply ()
            with error  ->
                System.Environment.Exit 0
    }
    MailboxProcessor.Start mbBody

Async.RunSynchronously (async {
    let! completed =
        let jobs = [|
            for i = 1 to 10 do
                async {
                    do! Async.Sleep 100
                    do! mb.PostAndAsyncReply(fun ch -> ch, i)
                    return i
                }
        |]
        Async.Parallel(jobs)

    printfn $"Completed {Seq.length completed} job(s)."
})
```

Btw. i changed the `seq {}` to an array, and additional removed the `maxDegreeOfParallelism` option. Otherwise the results seemed not to be very *parallel* in my tests. But you still can keep those if you want.

executing this program prints something like:

```
Work 10
Work 4
Work 9
Work 3
Work 8
```

Comment: Thank you, however I would like the program to stop when it hits an error. Yours prints the error and continues IIUIC

Comment: @sdgfsdh Then you should call something like `System.Environment.Exit`. An exception can be fetched, and is fetched in `MailboxProcessor`. I changed my code example. Now it aborts the program on the first exception.

Comment: It's better to use `Environment.FailFast` to kill application, because it supports exception and/or message logging into Event Viewer (windows). I'm not sure about logging behavior on linux